# What is the autoloading precedence with phar files involved

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following setting: I have a PHP project that uses a framework that itself has a dependency on a certain library. This library is used somewhere in the dependency tree of PHPUnit as well. As the version in the framework is fixed (from my perspective), this imposes a restriction on the possible versions of PHPUnit that can be installed (when installing as a composer dependency).

If I wanted to use a phar file of PHPUnit, the dependencies should be bundled. I think I read somewhere, that the internal library in the phar has precedence over external libraries to be used but I cannot find it anymore.

So: is it true that the bundled dependency will be used preferred when running PHPUnit as phar?
Do you have the source of that information anywhere by chance?

Comment: Regarding the source: it is in the build [`build.xml` file](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5.7/build.xml) building the phar from scope'd files, that is prefixing namespaces making all classes unique to Phpunit itself with the [`php-scoper` utility](https://github.com/humbug/php-scoper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (now) explained in the [documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/installation.html#phar-implementation-details):

> With the exception of classes such as PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase that are part of PHPUnit’s public API, all units of code bundled in PHPUnit’s PHAR distribution, including all dependencies such as vendor directories, are moved to a new and distinct namespace.
>
> PHPUnit’s PHAR distribution does not use dynamic autoloading to load the bundled units of code. Instead, all units of code bundled in the PHAR are loaded on startup.

Your question here prompted me to add this information to the documentation just now. Thanks!